# react-dates datepicker default popup behaviour

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-datepicker, react-dates

i m using react-dates ^18.4.0 on my react application and i noticed a weird behaviour on 'open'

When i click on `<Input box id="start date">` some times the `<DatePicker/>` popups immediatelly and sometimes it slowly opens from top to down.

I made a search on the **storybook** and it seems this is a default behaviour of the datepicker component.
http://airbnb.io/react-dates/?selectedKind=DateRangePicker%20%28DRP%29&selectedStory=default&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel

So if you click on the 'Start Date' or 'End Date', some times the dates component is shown with transition and sometimes not.

Has anybody come up with that issue ?
Can we fix it somehow with scss ?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this, not sure what the intention is. There is a transition on the `height` for `.DayPicker_transitionContainer__horizontal`. So I have just added `transition: none` to it, in my own css.

eg:

```
.myCustomPickerClassName .DayPicker .DayPicker_transitionContainer__horizontal {
  transition: none;
}
```

you'll have to get the specificity right, or use `!important`

Comment: What i need actually is the datepicker to open always with transition. What have you managed with that change ?

Comment: ah ok, I don't have a solution to that,